# Open Source Data Visualization Schema

Tags: releasing-data, visualization

I want to capture the data needed to create a visualization (data, series names, titles etc.) in a way that is not tied to my end charting library. The goal being that I could capture the charting data in a common way and let the UI take these definitions and transform them to target charting library at runtime (d3, high charts etc.)

Does anyone know of a robust / flexible data visualization schema that I could use?

Comment: Hi @will, have you had a look at Wilkinson's ["The Grammar of Graphics"](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZiwLCAAAQBAJ)?  Not sure if there's a single framework that can map data to any visualization library but this is a seminal effort in that spirit.

Answer (score 2):

"Data visualization" is a wide spectrum -- from tables to infographics, and everything in between.

But I did find one possible source: **https://help.plot.ly/json-chart-schema/**

> *The Plotly JSON visualization schema is a complete declarative format for creating, saving, and sharing interactive, scientific charts. The advantage of saving charts as JSON is portability - charts can be shared across any language or platform that understands the schema.*

and an example:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "x": [
                "giraffes", 
                "orangutans", 
                "monkeys"
            ], 
            "y": [
                20, 
                14, 
                23
            ], 
            "type": "bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

> The complete JSON schema is maintained as part of Plotly’s [V2 REST API](https://api.plot.ly/v2/):
>
> Fully formatted JSON chart schema for every chart type: https://api.plot.ly/v2/plot-schema?sha1=%27%27
>      Raw JSON (plain text) chart schema for every chart type: https://api.plot.ly/v2/plot-schema?format=json&sha1=%27%27

---

This page doesn't have license info, but plot.ly the company states this for plotly.js

> **Is Plotly.js Free?**
>
> Yes.   Plotly.js is free and open-source software, [licensed under the MIT license](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/LICENSE). It costs nothing to [install and use](https://plot.ly/javascript/getting-started). You can view the source, report issues or contribute using [our Github repository](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js).

https://plot.ly/javascript/is-plotly-free/